# Cakephp Auth login keeps redirecting to UserController->login

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Simple question

Here is the Auth related code in my AppController that all my Controllers inherit from.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth'=>array(
            //destination after logging in, or auto friendly fowarding depending on what user was trying to access
            'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'Access', 'action'=>'login'),  
            'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'Access', 'action'=>'logout'), 
            'authError'=>'You cannot access that page', //Error message whenever someone access a page without auth
            'authorize'=>array('Controller') //Where in our application that authorization will occur

        )
    );
```

Here is my Access Controller that is supposed to control the logins and logouts

```
class AccessController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Js' => array('Jquery'));


    public function index() {
        echo "index";
    }


    public function login() {

        $this->layout = 'login';


        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {

                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect');
            }
        }

    }



    public function logout() {

        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

Anytime I try to access a page so that the login page is prompted, the browser gives me an error:

```
The action login is not defined in controller UsersController
```

Now I am using UsersController for some other purpose (not for logging in and logging out) which is why i specified the AccessController in my AppController for the login/logout redirects.

Why is trying to pull up UsersController?

Answer (score 3):

I think i have fixed it. This website supports my claim
http://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/cakephp-logoutredirect-is-not-the-same-as-loginaction/

I had to add a loginAction to my Auth array to lead to the login screen. Apparently loginRedirect is not what I thought it was.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Auth'=>array(
        //destination after logging in, or auto friendly fowarding depending on what user was trying to access
        'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'access', 'action'=>'login'),
        'loginAction'=>array('controller'=>'access', 'action'=>'login'),
        'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'access', 'action'=>'logout'), 
        'authError'=>'You cannot access that page', //Error message whenever someone access a page without auth
        'authorize'=>array('Controller') //Where in our application that authorization will occur

    )
);
```

Comment: Did you also try changing where the loginRedirect points to?  Right now you have it pointing back to your login function.  For example, in my app (which uses a Users controller instead of Access) I have:

'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index')

which sends users to their homepage, instead of the login screen.

Comment: Hi Jackel Yeap i've fixed all that. Your comment is correct, loginRedirect should direct to the homepage, and not to the login action that shows the login page